# JPanel not being Displayed in my JFrame, but in new Window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, japplet

I believe I am doing something simple wrong; and my research has got me no where.

I created a stand alone Java application, that I am trying to convert to run as an applet. (Being an applet is a requirement).

I created a  JPanel class MazePanel,and I am trying to display it as an applet. When I run my Applet in Netbeans, 2 windows load. One is a blank Applet window, while the other is my Maze. I want the Maze (which is implemented in MazePanel), to display in my applet. Can anyone take a look at this, and tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
public class MazeApplet extends JApplet {


protected JFrame frame;
protected JPanel jPanel;
protected MazeBuilder builder;
protected MazeFactory factory;

public MazeApplet() {
    //Set up frame
    frame = new JFrame("Maze -- Builder");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable((true));

}

public void init() {

    factory = new ShoutMazeFactory();
    builder = new FactoryMazeBuilder(factory);
    Maze maze = MazeGameBuilder.createMaze(builder);
    maze.setCurrentRoom(1);
    jPanel = (new Maze.MazePanel(maze));
//Add jPanel to Frame
    frame.getContentPane().add(jPanel);
    frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Below is the JPanel Class I am trying to display

```
public class MazePanel extends JPanel{

protected Maze maze = new Maze();
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
Dimension dim = getSize(); 
g.setColor(Color.white);
g.fillRect(0, 0, dim.width, dim.height);    
g.setColor(Color.black);
  maze.draw(g);
  }    
}
```

Comment: If you don't want a JFrame, why are you creating one? Add the MazePanel to the MazeApplet.

Comment: Thanks! Ahh such an obvious answer and I missed it!

Comment: getContentPane().add(jPanel);

Comment: *"(Being an applet is a requirement)."*  Why?  If it were an applet that was free floating on the desk-top (outside a browser window) would that fulfill the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

While working in an applet you can't create a new frame which is the reason for the creation of the frame.

Start you initial panel in the init() block and then make panels visible or invisible depending on the need.

Comment: *"While working in an applet you can't create a new frame.."*  Of course you can.  It usually does not make sense to do so, but it is possible.